# How do I calculate the Expected value of this normal distribution?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, expected-value

I have a distribution Y<sub>i</sub> - BX<sub>i</sub> ~ N(0,T) and I'm having trouble calculating an element of the Expected Information matrix for it.

The density function should be f(Y, X; B, T) = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2πT}}$ e<sup>$\frac{-(Y-BX)^2}{2T}$</sup>

I calculated $\frac{d^2l}{dB^2}$   = $\frac{-n}{T}$ X<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>

And so the respective element for the matrix should be E[$\frac{-n}{T}$ X<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>] = $\frac{-n}{T}$ E[X<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>] but I'm having some trouble understanding how to calculate this expected value.

Is it correct to integrate the following and treat everything else as constant or is that wrong?

$$\int_\infty^\infty x^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2πT}}   e^{\frac{-(Y-BX)^2}{2T}} dx$$

edit: $\frac{d^2l}{dB^2}$ = $\frac{1}{T}$$\sum_{i=1}^n$  X<sub>i</sub>^2

Comment: where is the $n$ coming from in your $\frac{\partial^2\ell}{\partial B^2}$? And for the expectation, I'd recommend thinking about what is random and what isn't here

Comment: The n is the sample size that appears when I calculate the likelihood function.

Comment: Oh I think I made a mistake calculating it, I've edited the above, although I still have the same issue with the E[Xi^2]

Comment: yep that's correct for the Hessian! Now for the expectation, when we write the usual linear model of $y_i = x_i^T\beta + \varepsilon_i$ with $\varepsilon_i\stackrel{\text{iid}}\sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma^2)$, what's the distribution of $x_i$? What would $\text{E}_{Y\mid X}(x_i)$ be?

Comment: Actually you should still have a negative sign out front for the Hessian, this reflects that the log-likelihood is concave and the best 2nd order approximation is a "downward" paraboloid (which isn't even an approximation in this case, but in general i think that's a helpful way to remember whether a Hessian should be positive (semi)definite vs negative (semi)definite)

Comment: Since for *any* distribution $E[X^2]=\operatorname{Var}(X)+E[X]^2,$ you can (literally) read these two terms off the name of the distribution and plug them in.  No integration is necessary.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right, I missed the minus sign there. I'm not sure I follow your other comment, sorry my understanding here is not great. Is the distribution of the Xi not unknown?

Comment: @whuber But I don't think I can do this as I don't know the Variance or Mean of just X here since the model is Y-BX ~ N(0,T) rather than X~N(0,T)

Comment: What I've been getting at is are the $x_i$ even random, and if not, what's their expected value?

Comment: Yeah I appreciate that you're trying to help me figure it out myself haha, are you trying to hint towards a conditional probability identity? The only dependency I can think of is that the distribution of the Yi and the Xi should be similar? - I feel like I'm missing something basic.

Comment: What I'm getting at is in the usual setting the $x_i$ are not random and expectations here are with respect to the distribution of $y$ given $x$. This means $\text{E}(x_i) = x_i$, and fits the general result with generalized linear models that when we use the canonical link function (as is the case here) then the Hessian is nonrandom so its expected value is just the thing itself. If your $x_i$ are also random then this won;t be the case but i didn't get that sense from your question

Comment: Your language strongly suggests you view $Y$ as the random variable *conditional* on $X.$  Thus, the mean is $BX$ and the variance is $T.$ If not, then your question is incomplete because you haven't given any information about the distribution of $X.$